# How can i save richtextbox data in the same format in xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am doing a task as I have a RichtextBox in C# desktop application. User may enter data in it as a paragraph and my enter data in multiple paragraph format.

Example:
this is a line
this is a line
this is a line
this is a paragraph this is a paragraph this is a paragraph this is a paragraph this is a paragraph this is a paragraph this is a paragraph.

I want to save the above data in XML file in the same format so that if I view the file using xslt the data shoud be viewed in the same format as entered in the `RichtextBox.Data` may be complex.

Comment: So you basically want to convert RTF to XML?

Comment: To be honest, you probably don't need XSLT here. Just use C# to get the text from the RichTextBox and use that to build the XML manually.